# SQL запрос, группировка данных по неделям

Tags: sql, mysql

Всем привет. Нужна помощь в составлении SQL запроса.

Суть, есть таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `htable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `userid` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `items` set('item1','item2','item3','item4','item5') DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;
```

Есть запрос:

```
select week( from_unixtime(date),0 ) as hweek
 ,date_sub(from_unixtime(date), interval (dayofweek(from_unixtime(date))-1) day) as hstart
 ,date_add(from_unixtime(date), interval (7-dayofweek(from_unixtime(date))) day) as hend
 ,count(items) as hcount
 from htable where items LIKE '%item1%' AND (date BETWEEN 1393963200 AND 1396123200)
 group by week(from_unixtime(date))
```

Запрос выводит количество записей с items LIKE '%item1%' за промежуток времени 03/01/2014 - 03/30/2014 и группирует их по неделям, но есть одно но, если в какую-то неделю из промежутка нету записей, то в результаты запроса эти недели не попадают.

Вопрос: можно ли как-то добавить эти данные (чтобы выводило нули) в результат запроса?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В году 52 недели. Создать таблицу из 52 строк, и соединить (внешнее) её с вашим запросом по номеру недели.

```
create table T (dt datetime);
insert into T values('2014-02-20'),('2014-02-27'),('2014-03-02'),('2014-02-9'),('2014-03-25');
create table weeks(w int);
insert into weeks values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),
(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20),
(21),(22),(23),(24),(25),(26),(27),(28),(29),(30),
(31),(32),(33),(34),(35),(36),(37),(38),(39),(30),
(41),(42),(43),(44),(45),(46),(47),(48),(49),(50),
(51),(52);
SELECT W,WD FROM (
SELECT WEEK(DT) WD FROM t
) x
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT * FROM WEEKS CROSS JOIN (SELECT WEEK(MAX(DT)) WMAX, WEEK(MIN(DT)) WMIN FROM T) y) z ON WD=W
WHERE W BETWEEN WMIN AND WMAX;
```

Comment: Т.е. 52 столбца + 1 столбец, где хранить год.
Первым запросом добавлять/заменять данные в эту временную таблицу.
А вторым запросом доставать оттуда данные?

А если у меня в главной таблице будет несколько столбцов, по которым я захочу вести такую статистику? Т.е. напримпер: items1, items2, и.т.д. Тогда хранить данные в сериализованном виде?

Comment: Не достаточно хранить в таблице только номер недели, т.к. по нему не получится восстановить hstart и hend. Придется хранить все возможные значения: либо hyear, hweek, hstart, hend, либо hyearweek, hstart, hend (см. функцию mysql yearweek).  
Из таблицы будут браться только даты, не надо туда заносить данные из htable.  
Только учтите, что если забудете вовремя заполнить эту доп. таблицу, то получите всё те же недостающие строки в результате.

Comment: > Т.е. 52 столбца + 1 столбец, где хранить год.

Я говорю 52 строки, а столбец один который содержит числа от 1 до 52. Год хранить не нужно - достаточно добавить группировку по году в вашем запросе.
Но если вам больше нравится ответ, что такого сделать нельзя, то это ваше дело.

Comment: Если во вспомогательной таблице хранить только номер недели, то неизвестно откуда брать значения для hstart и hend. Если вы знаете, как это сделать - приведите пример sql-запроса

Comment: > то неизвестно откуда брать значения для hstart и hend.

Так из вашего же запроса и брать - во WHERE после соединения. Пример могу дать.

Comment: Да, непонятно :D
В исходном варианте запроса hstart и hend вычисляется из htable.date. Но после соединения некоторые строки в htable будут отсутствовать (в чем, собственно, и заключалась проблема), поэтому и hstart/hend вычислять не из чего. Так что пора уже писать SQL, не думаете?

Comment: > Так что пора уже писать SQL, не думаете?

Об этом я думаю в последнюю очередь :-), но пример добавил в ответ.

Comment: И где в примере даты? @lightcyber в своем запросе получает номер недели, а также первый и последний день недели. Номер получить это не проблема, а даты?

Answer (score 0):

При помощи средств MySQL этого сделать нельзя (если только не прибегать к дико шаманским методам). Но очень легко дополнить данные на стороне PHP (или что Вы используете).
Если Вы уверены, что для каждой недели есть хоть одна запись в таблице, но она не обязательно содержит item1, то можно сделать выборку без фильтра по items, а кол-во подходящих строк считать не как `count(items)`, а как `sum(items LIKE '%item1%')`. Но это хак системы, я бы в своем проекте такое не использовал. Первый вариант надежнее.

Comment: Нет, такой уверенности нету. Т.е. могут быть недели вообще без записей.
Дополнять результаты на php, конечно можно, но это нужно будет учитывать число дней в месяце / високосный/невисокосный год, просчитывать промежутки, и.т.д. Получается велосипед не очень хороший...

Comment: В PHP тоже есть средства для работы с датами. Совсем не обязательно просчитывать дни недели вручную.